# Function in javascript is returning undefined (NaN)?

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, undefined, series

We need the code for summation of the series up to nth term in javascript :
1/(2n+1)
When I executed the function series(80); it alerted NaN.
Code:

```
function series(n){
        var i;
        var s;
        for(i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            s = s + 1/(2*i+1);
        }

        alert(s);

    }
series(80);
```

Comment: you're declaring n twice and undefined is not a number. Remove var n and set initial numeric values.

Comment: `s` is undefined when you first use it. Your calculation is equivalent to `'undefined' + 1/(2*i+1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the default value on `s = 0`

```js
function series(n) {
  var i;
  var s = 0;
  var n;
  for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    s = s + 1 / (2 * i + 1);
  }

  alert(s);

}
series(80)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example and definitely worked no need to declare n because we pass it as argument in function.

```
function series(n) {
   var i, s = 0;
   for(i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
       s = s + 1/(2*i+1);
   }
   alert(s);
}
series(80);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x1ea748y/1/